# Clean and concise way to find active records that have the same id as another set of active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a table called shoppers and another table called `Users`. I have a `shopper_id` which is the foreign key in the `Shoppers` table and refers to the primary key `id` in the `Users` table.

I ran a query called `@shoppers = shoppers.where("some condition")`

This allowed me to get a set of shoppers who satisfy the condition. Next I would like to select those Users who have the same `id` as the `shopper_id` as the individual objects in `@shoppers.`

I know I could do this by writing a loop, but I am wondering if ruby on rails allows me to write a `Users.where` condition that can help me obtain the subset of user objects with the same `id` as `shopper_id` arranged in ascending order by the name field in the `Users` table.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell me the relation between `shoppers` and `users` please?

Comment: All the shoppers are users and are connected by a foreign key called shopper_id that matches the id in the users table

Comment: I mean the association. ***one-one*** ? Can you post the model code?

Comment: Yes it is a one-one association. Sorry the code has too many other unnecessary fields, but I hope this is enough information for you

Comment: How you set the foriegn-key? while creation of tables through migration or in your model?

Comment: I do it in the model

Comment: Could you show your associations (the lines containing `has_one` / `belongs_to`), please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
  @shoppers = Shopper.where("some condition")
  @users = User.where(id: @shoppers.collect(&:shopper_id)).order('name asc')
```

Comment: thanks . that seems to work. where can I learn more about functions such as collect

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/ this website has all the documentation regarding each ruby versions. helps me read details about methods. Please give it a try.:)

Comment: I am looking at the link. How do I navigate through so much documentation to find the functions that can help me achieve a specific task. e.g. it would help if you could tell me how did you decide to use this expression @shoppers.collect(&:shopper_id)

Comment: when you need to fetch something from array you can do that using collect. collect(&:#attribute or method). it will return you array of those object. then there is anther thing pluck. pluck is on the db level. It will only query the particular field from the table. you can use them based on scenario. .each is used to traverse along the array.